# WPF, C# static list<string> Binding to a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, list, static, listbox

Edit: This problem only occurs when I "Show.Dialog" a new WPF Window and use the Xaml in the new Window. If I copy the Xaml to my original window the LIST binds correctly without using static properties (and updates)! I can work with this, but is this normal? Is there a correct way of getting things to work properly with new Windows?

```
WorkOrderWindow WorkOrderWindow = new WorkOrderWindow();
WorkOrderWindow.ShowDialog();
```

I am binding a ListBox to a List. It works correctly when I make the List Static and comment out "NotifyPropertyChanged", but I need NotifyPropertyChanged and cannot implement NotifyPropertyChanged on a static. If I change my List to non-Static I get no items in my ListBox.

Changing from "static" and commenting out "NotifyPropertyChanged" is the difference between a ListBox filled with items or not.

I have no idea why this is happening. Can anyone explain to me and provide a solution? thanks.

this works as expected, (minus the ability to update the UI):

```
    private static List<string> _WorkOrderGroupsList;
    public static List<string> WorkOrderGroupsList
    {
        get { return _WorkOrderGroupsList; }
        set
        {
            _WorkOrderGroupsList = value;
            //NotifyPropertyChanged("WorkOrderGroupsList");
        }
    }
```

This does not work:

```
    private List<string> _WorkOrderGroupsList;
    public List<string> WorkOrderGroupsList
    {
        get { return _WorkOrderGroupsList; }
        set
        {
            _WorkOrderGroupsList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("WorkOrderGroupsList");
        }
    }
```

WPF:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkOrderGroupsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"  
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
              </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     </ListBox >
```

Comment: *cannot implement NotifyPropertyChanged on a static [class]* is not true. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I will look into the other question, but to be clear. I am not trying to make the property static. I am asking why things won't work the way I normally bind int's, string's, etc. I am not trying to create a static, so I don't believe the question is a duplicate.

Comment: List<> objects can't properly notify. Try using an ObservableCollection<>  instead. They work exactly like Lists, but can notify bindings of updates (reference System.Collections).